# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' error?

Tags: python

I am trying to do a simple calculation (which later will be done on an array) and getting the aforementioned error.

> can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

`8.99*[-(math.log(1-0.5))**(1/2.87)]`

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the square brackets?

Comment: I guess the reason is the [ ] brackets as it would be understood as a list, try to use () only.

Comment: note that `9*[-(math.log(1-0.5))**(1/2.87)]` would work (multiplication of a `list` with an `integer`) - however, this would give you a list with 9 references to the value `-(math.log(1-0.5))**(1/2.87)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets turn the result of `-(math.log(1-0.5))**(1/2.87)` into a list with a single element. The error message is due to the "multiplication" of the list by 8.99. The `*` operator when applied to a list means to repeat the list elements that many times and to create a new list. e.g. `5 * [1]` becomes `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. Python is complaining that you can't repeat the elements 8.99 times.

You can just remove the square brackets to get a valid answer

```
8.99 * -(math.log(1 - 0.5)) ** (1 / 2.87)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to multiply a list (denoted by square brackets) as a number. Try

`8.99*(-(math.log(1-0.5))**(1/2.87))` instead.